# Converting UK date to UTC

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called pm_msg with a time column and the following values:

```
07-02-2013 18:11:00
27-01-2013 16:02:44
28-01-2013 10:30:26
30-01-2013 13:30:06
```

I would like to convert them to Unix timestamp while running an PDO SQL query.
This is what I've done so far, but it seems to return an error. How should I go about doing it?

```
$sql = "SELECT * from pm_msg ORDER BY (strtotime(time)) ASC;";
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` does not exist in MySQL, you want the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from pm_msg ORDER BY (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)) ASC;";
```

But - you don't need to convert it to a UNIX timestamp just to sort it. Sorting works correctly on dates? Maybe you intend to add the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` to the `SELECT` portion?

Comment: @methuselah PDO is just a client library for a MySQL connection. It doesn't alter the queries nor does it remove functionality. If MySQL supports the function, PDO will "support" the function.

Comment: I think you may have overlooked the fact that he is using a UK date/timestamp

Answer (score 0):

UTC is more or less the same as GMT - does not take into account of DST.

So in spring and autumn you need to take that into account.

But to convert a date/time into unixtime using SQL see [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) or [UNIXTIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to setup your time column as **datetime**, if you are using something like **varchar** right now.